# Access and update variables in model rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have three views that have to display values from a hash in a model. Two of the views have to be able to update the values in the hash.

1. How do I access the varable's values in the views. (preferably directly and without using an additional controller) I currently use global variables, but have been told instance variables would make more sense.
2. How do I write changes to the model? I have a controller that handles the input, but I don't know how to actually update the model.

Edit: That's the what the hash looks like

```
$hash = {
  'sumOfProjects' => $sumOfProjects,
  'project1' => {
      'title' => $project_title_1,
```

and so on...

Comment: Add some related code to the question

Comment: Hi @Kpop Europe. Please don't put two questions in one. Also try to search fro answers on the site, before you post your own question. I am sure all your question already have been answered somewhere here on this site.

Comment: @RolandStuder Hey! Sadly, no... I've been working on this for weeks :c

Comment: Then you need to work on the fundamentals. You really shouldn't use global variables. I recommend to have a look at https://www.theodinproject.com/courses The time investment will be worth it.

Comment: @KpopEurope But to actually be able to help you anyway you need to post your controller code that corresponds to the view and what you tried in the view.

Comment: @KpopEurope Also if you want to persists the data across Server restarts, or not? If yes, you need to save the data in a database so would need to look at ActiveRecord.

Comment: @RolandStuder The hash is saved to a yaml file and then pushed to git.

Comment: @KpopEurope Ah fair enough. I made too many assumptions. But as I said, post the relevant code bits. You are getting downvotes, because your question is not answerable in the current state. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve If you don't provide such an example you will not get any help. You have to help yourself ;-)

Answer (score 1):

create a model

```
rails g model hash someofproject Project1 title
```

and then

```
rake db:migrate
```

give the input and check by using rails console

```
rails c
Hash.new
Hash.create()
```